# Access web app on Linux server from laptop via network bridge, no router

Tags: networking, ip, webserver, bridge, ubuntu-18.04

I have a web app on an Ubuntu 18.04 Linux web server, and I simply want to access it from a web browser on my laptop, which is connected to the server directly via ethernet cable.

I can do this if both computers have static IP addresses on the same network (eg 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0). However, the client computer is always changing so setting up a static IP is too much work for my customers.

*Can I accomplish the same thing with a network bridge or something like that, so that the client laptop does not need a static IP address?*

Background: The server is actually an IoT gateway, and the web app is an admin console for setting the cellular modem APN on the gateway. I want to connect the laptop via ethernet directly to the server gateway, type a static IP address into the laptop's browser, and set the cellular APN via the convenient web app.

Thanks!!

EDIT: Here is a very similar question I previously asked. This new question is specifically about network bridges or other alternatives to having two static IP addresses:
[Access web app on Linux server from laptop via ethernet cable, no router](https://superuser.com/questions/1512989/access-web-app-on-linux-server-from-laptop-via-ethernet-cable-no-router)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your setup correctly, but what stops you from running a DHCP server on the webapp server, so the client computer gets a valid IP in the correct private range automatically when you connect it via ethernet cable? No "network bridge" needed.

Comment: "However, the client computer is always changing so setting up a static IP is too much work for my customers." - who controls the configuration of the clients PC/network? If this is an isolated device, then there isn't any configuration on the client until it's configured? If you're adding this to an existing customer network, you need to get the IP they want you to use, from them...

Comment: @dirkt 's DHCP server is a very promising solution. I'll try it today. There is no client network. Just a lonely remote IoT gateway (server) and random laptops (client computers) owned by the customer. The gateway/server won't have cellular internet access until the customer connects a laptop and sets the cellular APN via the web app. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: FYI, the DHCP server worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dirkt already mentioned, you MUST have a DHCP server in Linux machine (fairly easy to setup) if you want the connecting laptop to get an automatic IP address. 
As an advanced setup, you can setup the laptop's network card to accept DHCP as primary, and have alternatively a static IP, but I don't think that solves your problem since you will have to do this setup to every connecting laptop, right?

Comment: Excellent suggestion. It worked!! You're correct that I don't want to have to configure anything on the laptop because it could be a different laptop client every time.